# Sub-Menu is not clickable or active in mobile view only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Sub-menus are working and clickable in desktop view and tablet view but not working in mobile view 
[website](https://refrigeratorserviceacrepair.com/) and Here are menus, Where I am going wrong (It's a Wordpress theme based website)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give it z-index of 9999, maybe some other div has bigger z-index.

Comment: on the whole menu on just the buttons inside?

Comment: just button inside like *Toshiba*  *Bosch* every please check the website once

Comment: if you remove the position:relative from .elementor-nav-menu li, it should work

Comment: from inspect element removing that didnt make any change to the style, so it might work just fine by deleting it